# How to I remove the all meta-data, identify objects, embedded-data, non-pdf/embedded binary, identity(IDs), embedded-character etc in PDF file?

Tags: embedded, pdf, data, file-metadata

I want convert the PDF to only TEXT(as unicode) & IMAGE based PDF.

So the pdf document should consist only of images and text. I want to do this in a GNU/Linux environment, it would be better for me if there is a utility that I can do from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF file format is a complex envelope with a core of PostScript file.
If you need a well-formed PDF, to search-and-index it, and extract data in a human readable way you can do very little things if the PDF was made by a PDF generator that simpy packs data with no optimization.
There are tools, in Linux, for managing and optimizing PDFs, but none of them solves all the problems of PDFs.
For instance, pdftools,pdftk and others.